# Problema con select para filtro de precio PHP MYSQL JQuery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Tengo un formulario el cual contiene un `select`, para poder filtrar por mayor o menor precio, cuando selecciono una opción si realiza el filtrado, el problema es que el `select` nunca cambia de opción siempre se queda en la primera opción.

Yo creo que tiene que ver algo con el atributo `selected= "selected"`, lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no me ha resultado, e incluso he intentado poner `.atrr('selected', true)` desde *JQuery*, pero cuando intento esto no me respeta la instruccion `$("#search_form").submit();`

Otra cosa para el front uso *materializecss*

-------------------HTML-----------------

```
      <form method="get" id="search_form"><!--Formulario para filtros-->

      <select name="prices" id="price">
      <option value="ASC"<?php
      if (isset($_GET['prices'])
       && $_GET['prices'] == 'ASC') {
      $selected = ' selected="selected"';
      }
       ?> <?php $selected?>>ASC</option>

      <option value="DESC"<?php
      if (isset($_GET['prices'])
       && $_GET['prices'] == 'DESC') {
     $selected = ' selected="selected"';
      }
      ?> <?php $selected?>>DESC</option>

      </select>

       <label>Ordena Por:</label>
```

--------------------JQuery----------------------------------

```
     $('select#price').change(function(){

      $("#search_form").submit();
       return false;  



       });
```

------------------PHP----------------------------------------

```
      if(isset($_GET['prices']) && $_GET['prices']!="") :

       if($_GET['prices']=='ASC'):

       $sql .= " ORDER BY precio ASC";   


       elseif($_GET['prices']=='DESC'):

       $sql .=" ORDER BY precio DESC";


        endif;   

       endif;
```

Comment: Me parece que estas mezclando `GET` y `POST`

Comment: ya había corregido eso y aun falla :(

Comment: para ser sincero soy principiante en esto, tal vez haya alguna otra forma de ordenar por precio?

Comment: Intenta esto, abre el inspector de codigo de tu navegador y revisa como se esta renderizando el elemento select en tu pagina

Comment: Intentalo asi: `<option value="DESC"<?php
      if (isset($_GET['prices'])
       && $_GET['prices'] == 'DESC') {
     echo ' selected="selected"';
      } ?>>DESC</option>`

Comment: Según yo le hace falta un `echo` a la variable `selected` en la línea `?> <?php $selected?>>DESC</option>`

Comment: alanfcm y J. Castro, son los mejores llevaba tiempo dándole vueltas a este problema, gracias por su colaboración :)

Comment: @alanfcm dado que al parecer el OP resolvió su problema, abogo por una respuesta tuya en la que se muestre al OP la forma de escribir un código más claro, por ejemplo concatenando una sola variable de salida que impedirá la *horrible* mezcla de código PHP/HMTL que hace los programas ilegibles y que dan pie a este tipo de errores que conducen a *llevar tiempo dándole vueltas* como él mismo dice. Imagínate... un `if` con `isset` con `&&` con `$_GET` con `echo` dentro de un  `option` ... eso debería estar prohibido :)

Answer (score 1):

Aunque tu problema se puede solucionar agregando un simple `echo`, es bueno que aprendas a desarrollar codigo mas legible, utilizando las mejores practicas.  Por ejemplo, no necesitas mezclar codigo HTML con PHP.  Puedes generar todo tu HTML guardandolo en una variable de salida.

Otra buena practica es la indentacion.  Aunque el HTML sea un string, siempre es bueno llevar la indentacion como si escribieras HTML regular.  En tu caso es una forma simple, pero cuando el contenido es mas extenso, eso te ayudara a no cometer errores.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
  $HTML = '<form method="get" id="search_form">
              <select name="prices" id="price">
                  <option value="ASC"';
  if (isset($_GET['prices']) && $_GET['prices'] == 'ASC') {
       $HTML .= ' selected="selected"';
  }
  $HTML .=        '>ASC</option>
                  <option value="DESC"';
  if (isset($_GET['prices']) && $_GET['prices'] == 'DESC') {
      $HTML .= ' selected="selected"';
  }
  $HTML .=       '>DESC</option>
              </select>
              <label>Ordena Por:</label>
          </form>';
  echo $HTML;
?>
```

Comment: Ya veo, esto se ve mucho mejor organizado, muchas gracias por las criticas constructivas es de gran ayuda para mi, para hacer un mejor código limpio y legible :) @alanfcm